# Trying to add different rows together that share some of the same info, but not all, using pandas

Tags: pandas-groupby

The easiest way to explain is to list the excel table I am working with first:

Charge Date___ CPT Code____  Payer Name_______  Ins Payment______  pt Payment

Date1 _________Code1 ________Ins Name ____________100 _________________0

Date1 _________Code1 ________No Name _______________0 ________________32

I have been able to combine like rows, such as pt name and CPT Code with groupby. I want to be able to total the pt payment with ins payment, but I am having trouble since the pt payment is listed under payer name as No Name, so I cannot combine the rows. What is the best way to get the total of these rows when I have much more data to work with?

Thanks!